# JavaScript не видит метод класса

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function Ball(param) {
    this._radius = param.radius;
    this._color = param.color;
}

Ball.protorype = {
    constructor: Ball,

    INCREMENTATION_STEP: 5,

    draw: function () {
        console.log("ball drawn with radius:" + this._radius + " and color: " + this._color);
    },
    inc: function () {
        this._radius += this.INCREMENTATION_STEP;
    }
}

bb = new Ball({
    radius: 100,
    color: "red"
});
bb.draw();
```

Он не видит метод draw и пишет:

> bb.draw is not a function.

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет такого ключевого слова протоРайп. Зато есть протоТайп.

```
Ball.protorype = {
```

После исправления все заработало.

Comment: гг, глаз - алмаз